# How to count value across multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame relative to motorcycle.
The dataset has 1000 rows and 30 columns.

For example,

```
date motor1 motor2 motor3 vehicle1  vehicle2 reason 
2010 Honda   NaN    NaN    Sedan     NaN        *    
  :
2012 Yamaha  Kymco  NaN    Truck     Sedan      *  
  :
2013 Harley  Kymco  Kymco  Ambulance NaN        *     
  :
```

I want to create a new column in order to record the value across columns without null value.

The output I expect is:

```
year motor1 motor2 motor3 vehicle1  vehicle2 reason count
2010 Honda   NaN    NaN    Sedan     NaN        *     2
  :
2012 Yamaha  Kymco  NaN    Truck     Sedan      *     4
  :
2013 Harley  Kymco  Kymco  Ambulance  NaN       *     4
  :
```

Additionally, because the data is arranged by year, I also want to set a condition for a specific year and just see how many vehicles and motorcycles involved in that specific year.

Initially, I want to use `groupby` function + `count` function +`conditional` function, but I cannot get what I want.

Is there any elegant way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `notna` and sum across columns to get the non-null count:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2010, 'Honda', np.nan, np.nan, 'Sedan', np.nan, '*'],
                   [2012, 'Yamaha', 'Kymco', np.nan, 'Truck', 'Sedan', '*'],
                   [2014, 'Harley', 'Kymco', 'Kymco', 'Ambulance', np.nan, '*']], columns=['year', 'motor1', 'motor2', 'motor3', 'vehicle1', 'vehicle2', 'reason'])

result = df.assign(count=df.loc[:, 'motor1':'vehicle2'].notna().sum(axis=1))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
   year  motor1 motor2 motor3   vehicle1 vehicle2 reason  count
0  2010   Honda    NaN    NaN      Sedan      NaN      *      2
1  2012  Yamaha  Kymco    NaN      Truck    Sedan      *      4
2  2014  Harley  Kymco  Kymco  Ambulance      NaN      *      4
```

To look at a particular year, you can just use boolean indexing:

```
print(result[result['year'] == 2010])
```

Output:

```
   year motor1 motor2 motor3 vehicle1 vehicle2 reason  count
0  2010  Honda    NaN    NaN    Sedan      NaN      *      2
```

Comment: Thanks, gmds! I appreciate your reply to my problem. That's an excellent and smart solution! From your solution, I learn how to use 'count', 'loc', and 'notna' function to filter data. Thank you for the elegant method!

Answer (score 1):

We can do that by counting the amount of `NaN` with [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) over `axis=1`. But first we filter with [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to get the columns which end with a number:

```
df['count'] = df.filter(regex='\d$').notna().sum(axis=1)
```

---

```
   date  motor1 motor2 motor3   vehicle1 vehicle2 reason  count
0  2010   Honda    NaN    NaN      Sedan      NaN      *      2
1  2012  Yamaha  Kymco    NaN      Truck    Sedan      *      4
2  2013  Harley  Kymco  Kymco  Ambulance      NaN      *      4
```

**Explanation** regex:

- `\d` is a number
- `$` is the end of a string.

Comment: I even did not notice all the items end with a number! Thanks for your advice for an alternative way to filter the data frame!